# HttpWebRequest POST or GET json web form

Tags: vb.net

I initiated my HttpWebRequest and got response below code.

`www.mywebsite.com/post?guid=fce4674d-bbf3-4208-8b72-26a2077df872-15bcf50da73`

Now, Should I send a GET or POST??  as I tried both but still not working...
but when I paste this code in the Browser it displays the Web Form including all the info I inputted in.

Can you help please?

**Code to Send GET Request**

```html
Public Sub MakeRequestsGET()
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim responseText As String

        If Request_getForm(response) Then
            responseText = ReadResponse(response)

            Form3.TextBox6.Text = responseText

            response.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ReadResponse(response As HttpWebResponse) As String
        Using responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim streamToRead As Stream = responseStream
            If response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip") Then
                streamToRead = New GZipStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            ElseIf response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate") Then
                streamToRead = New DeflateStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            End If

            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(streamToRead, Encoding.UTF8)
                Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function Request_getForm(ByRef response As HttpWebResponse) As Boolean
        response = Nothing

        Try
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.villageform.ct/post?guid=f0e7-b204-4azzza-ae18-4ab2a62-15brtrtyr15db), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer

            request.KeepAlive = True
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
            request.Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36"

            request.CookieContainer = GetPostcookie

            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8")

            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)
            GetPostcookie = tempCookies

        Catch e As WebException
            If e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
                response = DirectCast(e.Response, HttpWebResponse)
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            If response IsNot Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            Return False
        End Try

        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

Here's the code to send POST

```html
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.IO.Compression

Module CleanCodePost

    Public LastPostcookie As CookieContainer

    'Calls request functions sequentially.
    Public Sub MakeRequestsCleanPost()
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse
        Dim responseText As String

        If Request_submitForm(response) Then
            'Success, possibly use response.
            responseText = ReadResponse(response)

            Form3.txtbx_descript.Text = responseText

            response.Close()
        Else
            'Failure, cannot use response.
        End If
    End Sub

    'Returns the text contained in the response.  For example, the page HTML.  Only handles the most common HTTP encodings.
    Private Function ReadResponse(response As HttpWebResponse) As String
        Using responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim streamToRead As Stream = responseStream
            If response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip") Then
                streamToRead = New GZipStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            ElseIf response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate") Then
                streamToRead = New DeflateStream(streamToRead, CompressionMode.Decompress)
            End If

            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(streamToRead, Encoding.UTF8)
                Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

   
    Private Function Request_submitForm(ByRef response As HttpWebResponse) As Boolean
        response = Nothing

        Try
            'Create request to URL.
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.villageform.ct"), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer

            'Set request headers.
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            request.KeepAlive = True
            request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
            request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.villageform.ct")
            request.Headers.Add("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest")
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"

            request.CookieContainer = logincookiePost

            request.ContentType = "application/json"
            request.Referer = "https://www.villageform.ct/post"
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate, br")
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US,en;q=0.8")

            'Set request method
            request.Method = "POST"

            ' Disable 'Expect: 100-continue' behavior. More info: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/05/15/http-web-request-expect-100-continue.aspx
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False

            'Set request body.
            Dim body As String = "{""ads"":[{""title"":""My Travel to Venezuela"",""description"":""Testingkjshdjkjsdhsjdhfsd &nbsp;sdoisodfsdjk ksjdkjfskjfkjkj jlskdfjsldkjfksjdkjf kj kskdjkjsdkjfkj kskdklflfgdkkdfjk kldjfdlkfjgdkjfkjgkk kdfkjgkdfk kj dkfkdkjf kjdfkgkdfgkj jkldfjdfklgj kl dkfjdkfk kdfjdklfjgkldfjdklfgjdfkgkdjfd"",""phone"":""0123456789"",""categoryId"":9250,""categoryName"":""Computer Operators"",""parentCategory"":8,""location"":{""latitude"":-33.892333,""longitude"":18.510218,""radius"":2000},""categoryAttributes"":[],""imageUrls"":[]}]}"

            Dim postBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)
            request.CookieContainer = logincookiePost
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length
            Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
            stream.Close()

            'Get response to request.
            response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

            tempCookies.Add(response.Cookies)
            LastPostcookie = tempCookies

        Catch e As WebException
            'ProtocolError indicates a valid HTTP response, but with a non-200 status code (e.g. 304 Not Modified, 404 Not Found)
            If e.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
                response = DirectCast(e.Response, HttpWebResponse)
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            If response IsNot Nothing Then
                response.Close()
            End If
            Return False
        End Try

        Return True
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: That depends on the server. Show some server code or documentation.

Comment: _I tried both but still not working_ - what you mean by "not working"? Show your code which you tried. If you pass that in browser and it "works" then it is definitely GET request.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are saying. You post a webform and receive a link? So the POST works. Since, when you paste the link in the browser, you'll see the inserted data. This means you'll need to GET the data from the link. However, I don't see code that you can use for that, so you'll need to add a function to GET the data. Please note that method=GET doesn't have a body.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I edited my first post and added the code to send GET request that gets cookie from the previous POST request. Please I think I didn't set the cookie very well, if you can help.